# how to let PHP soap server communicate with C soap client?

Tags: php, soap

It work when it is another way round. php soap client communicate with c soap server.
Now I'm stuck at the first step on how to do the PHP soap server communicate with C soap client? any idea?

Comment: Uggg...I've worked with `SOAP` objects in PHP and its often tricky to get all the variables to line up.  I would be interested to know if there were some better wrappers to communicate at this layer than vanilla PEAR classes.  +1

Comment: SOAP is language agnostic, so what is the problem?